# How to modify binutils 2.29 Makefile.am and recreate a new Makefile?

Tags: automake, libtool, binutils, autoreconf

I have changed a Makefile.am inside binutils-2.29/binutils directory to create a new library. So I'm running the following command to create a new Makefile

```
dinesh@dinesh-HP-Ubuntu:/home/packages/binutils-2.29$ sudo libtoolize && aclocal -I./ && autoreconf && automake
```

It gives me following error:

```
dinesh@dinesh-HP-Ubuntu:/home/packages/binutils-2.29$ sudo libtoolize && aclocal -I./ && autoreconf && automake
libtoolize: Consider adding '-I m4' to ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in Makefile.am.
autom4te: cannot open autom4te.cache/requests: Permission denied
aclocal: error: echo failed with exit status: 1
```

But there is no Makefile.am in the Parent directory, there are Makefile.am inside sub directories.
When i search for Makefile.am I get this:

```
dinesh@dinesh-HP-Ubuntu:/home/packages/binutils-2.29$ find -iname "Makefile.am" | xargs grep -inr "ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS"
./gas/Makefile.am:21:ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I .. -I ../config -I ../bfd
./gold/Makefile.am:26:ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I ../bfd -I ../config
./opcodes/Makefile.am:21:ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I .. -I ../config -I ../bfd
./binutils/Makefile.am:21:ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I .. -I ../config -I ../bfd
./ld/Makefile.am:21:ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I .. -I ../config -I ../bfd
./zlib/Makefile.am:5:ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I .. -I ../config
./gprof/Makefile.am:21:ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I .. -I ../config -I ../bfd
./bfd/Makefile.am:21:ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I . -I .. -I ../config
```

In which Makefile.am should I add -I m4 ?

Also In parent directory there are   Makefiles with different extensions

```
dinesh@dinesh-HP-Ubuntu:/home/packages/binutils-2.29$ ls Makefile.*
Makefile.def  Makefile.in  Makefile.tpl
```